# Responsive image issue in materializecss

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I am creating a website with materializecss and having some issue with FAB and responsive image. For FAB issue I already did a post here.

[floating button issue in material css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63997945/floating-button-issue-in-material-css?noredirect=1#comment113183776_63997945)

But I need some help for responsive image. Its always coming in oval shape. Ii I use respoonsive image in collection it is working fine. Not sure how to get a prefect shape,[image]

html :

```
<div class="user-feed-main-box box">
    <ul class="collection">
        <li class="collection-item avatar">
          <img src="" alt="" class="circle">
          <span class="title"><p><a href="#one!">user</a> Shared a post <a href="#one!">Art</a> </p></span>
          <p> <label for="icon_prefix"><i class="material-icons left">timer</i>a min ago.</label> <br>
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s2">
            <div class="container">
                <img src="" alt="" class="responsive-img circle">
            </div>
                   
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p><a href="#one!">User</a> Shared a post <a href="#one!">Art</a> </p>
            <label for="icon_prefix"><i class="material-icons left">timer</i>a min ago.</label>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam eos in ea dolor eligendi repudiandae
            praesentium
            modi. Consequuntur, accusantium culpa! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni
            sapiente ipsa amet eos officiis aperiam atque. Nemo corporis quibusdam ipsa placeat voluptate fugiat fuga
            veniam possimus maxime doloremque veritatis ullam quam odit eligendi, id, sequi quas consequuntur
            perferendis accusamus, harum culpa quis animi. Minima, est minus? Optio dolor mollitia perspiciatis.</p>
        <div class="carousel carousel-slider">
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img
                    src=""></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img
                    src=""></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img
                    src=""></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img
                    src=""></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img
                    src=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</d
```

Comment: please add circle img to ` border-radius:50%;` width specific **equal width and height**.

Comment: This id correcly working for me :) [codepen demo](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/NWNeGdE)

Comment: Can you added this CDN 
```<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>```

Comment: Can you please check the code pen. https://codepen.io/subhanan-ganguli/pen/JjXwYvN

Comment: yes i checked. The codepen working correclty ?

Comment: it is not working still coming as oval shape. can you please check my code pen ? I have uploaded the entire code.

Comment: Probably it may causing due to grid. but not able to figure out

Answer (score 0):

There was a [reported issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/5537) similar to this in the [Materialize GitHub repo](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize). It appears the solution for that was to not use materialize and instead implement the below.

```
  .ratio {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

And then change the `img` html to

```
<div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image:url('somepicture.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: This is working perfectly but not for small sceen. It is getting too small in mobile screen.